# Remap keys from SteelSeries G6v2

Tags: keyboard, remapping

I bought a g6v2 from steelseries for the mechanical feeling of the keyboard

Unfortunately, they disabled the left windows key and replaced it with something akin to "FN" keys often found on laptops. By pressing the "Steel series button" and F1-6, you can access media control features such as volume up/down, play/pause ...

I really like the left windows button. It allows fast Run and Explorer shortcuts. It allows to popup the windows start menu while my right hand is still on the mouse.

Is it possible to remap that key with the windows key?

Comment: I purchased a SteelSeries 6Gv2 today but upon plugging it in realized that the left Windows key was actually a Fn key, so no software solution is possible. I use that Windows key extensively so I simply had to find a solution.

On checking GeekHack I noted that somebody had successfully dissembled the keyboard (4 screws, don't force anything) and soldered two wires connecting the two pads of the Right Windows button (WIN-L C0 and R1) to the similarly-labeled pads on the Left Windows button (WIN-R C9 and R2, resp.). You don't need to cut any circuit board traces so the mod is reversible. Works!

Comment: Wow, this is genius! I resorted to remap <kbd>Caps Locks</kbd> to <kbd>Windows</kbd>. I got used to it pretty fast but it gets a little weird when you switch to regular layouts

Comment: This demonstrates one benefit of a mechanical keyboard.

I posted how to do this on Overclock, which has a photo as well. See:
http://www.overclock.net/t/1015241/steelseries-6gv2-remap-media-button#post_24953282

Comment: @user1190 Just wondering.. how did you remap the keys (which file/directory did you open?)?

Answer (score 2):

> Unfortunately, the SteelSeries key functions as a "FN" key would on a
>   keyboard - this enables you to use the extra features on the F1-F12
>   keys at the top of the board.
>
> But this functionality is hard-wired and programmed into the board, so
>   it cannot be changed to do something else.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround for this was to use the Ctrl key as Command, and the Windows (Command) key as the less frequently used Ctrl.

This has the added bonus of feeling natural, as the command key for Mac works like the control key for Windows. (Everybody who steps up to my keyboard uses it that way as their first instinct. Even I keep forgetting, after 9 months of using a PC keyboard with a Mac. It's also how I set it up for my mother.)